# Zip file corrupted (sort of) after SFTP transfer/put (Jsch)

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

This is the code I use for sending a file through SFTP:

```
private void send (String sftpHost, int sftpPort, String user, String sshPrivateKeyPath, String sshPassphrase, String sftpDir, String fileName) {
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.addIdentity(sshPrivateKeyPath, sshPassphrase);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(sftpDir);
        File f = new File(fileName);
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        channelSftp.put(fis, f.getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("sending file failed", ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if(fis != null) fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error closing stream", e);
        }
        if(channelSftp != null) channelSftp.exit();
        if(channel != null) channel.disconnect();
        if(session != null) session.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Both machines are CentOS 6.5 VMs, java 1.7.0_51, OpenJDK, tomcat 7.0.50

The zip works on the source/client server with unzip -Z. On the destination/server, I get this error:

```
Archive:  filename.zip
[filename.zip]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of filename.zip or
          filename.zip.zip, and cannot find filename.zip.ZIP, period.
```

The file size also is changed:

Source (ok)

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 49170 Oct 10 15:35 filename.zip
```

Detination (corrupted)

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 45710 Oct 10 15:35 filename.zip
```

I also tried running jar -tf on the corrupted file and got:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

But when I tried jar xvf, it successfully extracted the files. So it's not totally "corrupted"

I also tried transferring via WinSCP to my Windows 7 machine and tried 7zip, but it also couldn't open the file.

I was thinking maybe Jsch has a setting for binary files but I haven't found any.

Thanks for any help/direction you can give

UPDATE 1: I've also tried Jsch's SCP interface with the same results

UPDATE 2: I've tried sshj sftp with the same results. So not a jsch problem...

UPDATE 3: I've also tried adding the code below. Though the file size changed, it still wouldn't open with unzip -Z

```
config.put("compression.s2c", "none");
config.put("compression.c2s", "none");
config.put("compression_level", "0");
```

Comment: Here is [the ZIP spec](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).  It sounds like the file has been truncated.  Compare the length before and after transfer.

Comment: Thanks, why would it truncate though?

Comment: Dunno -- I've never heard of a file transfer truncating data before (at least not since Tuesday).

Comment: Also tried Jsch SCP, same result. Will likely try a different library next

Comment: Try with various length files and see if very short ones get through OK.  I don't know exactly which protocol you're using but it's common for protocols to send data in chunks, and the receiving end often must be coded to receive the chunks and concatenate them.  It's a common newbie error to only receive the first chunk and try to use that.

Comment: I've tried with a 1 kb file. same thing. resulting file is 333b.

Comment: Compare the received file to what was sent.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with compare? programmatically? file sizes are different at source and destination

Comment: You sure there is no `IOException?`

Comment: @EJP Yes, file was successfully sent. There is some logging code after put(). I just removed it here to simplify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was all caused by my stupidity. The zipoutstream used to create the zip used by this code was not closed yet i.e. zip creation and file sending were in the same try - catch - finally block. Sorry for wasting anybody's time.